# raising to the same power

Tags: exponentiation

- when we add the same number many times we can use multiplication for shorter: $$2+2+2+2 = 2\times4$$
- when we multiply the same number many times we can use exponentiation for shorter: $$2\times2\times2\times2 = 2^4$$
- is there next level of shorter form equivalent to rising to the same power over and over again?
  $$2^{2^{2^2}} = ?(2,4)$$
  In the above example there is not much of shortening because we can mulitply powers and have
  $$2^8 = ?(2,4)$$
  But look at this:
  $$1000^{1000^{1000^{1000^{1000^{1000}}}}} = 1000^{1000000000000000} = ?(1000,6)$$
- if such a operation exists what about next levels of  shortening?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

Comment: Remember that $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$ and not $((a^b)^c)$. So $2^{2^{2^{2}}}\neq 2^8$.

Comment: I'd suggest starting from the WP article on tetration, which is to exponentiation as exponentiation is to multiplication. That will also lead to to Knuth up-arrow notation.

Comment: And as noted, $2^{2^{2^{2}}} \neq 2^8$, and is instead $2^16$. These functions are sometimes called "hyperoperations," represented as $H_n(a,b)$, where $a$ is the base and $b$ is the equivalent of an exponent. The $n$ subscript is the "level" of hyperoperations: e.g., $H_1(2,3)= 2 \times 3, H_4(2,2)$ is the example above, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're after something like Knuth's up-arrow notation. This has been explained on this site. See [How exactly does Knuth's Up-Arrow notation work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213491/how-exactly-does-knuths-up-arrow-notation-work)

Comment: This could have been a comment rather than an answer.